# tvOS CollectionView Selected Items Render Slow

Tags: ios, swift, tvos, collectionview

I'm having a collectionview setup, with local data and multiselect enabled. When I run this on an actual device I'm having some rendering issues. When I scroll superfast it takes a while before the active cells show up. They remain inactive for a little while when I stop and then suddenly pop up.

On didSelect I'm doing the following;

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! FRMenuCollectionViewCell
    let selectedCells:[IndexPath] = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems!
    cell.isSelected = true

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        let item = fixedData[indexPath.row]
        itemSelection.append(item)
        break
    case 1:
        handleContinentSelection(with: indexPath)
        break
    default:
        print("An unexpected case occured")
    }
}


func handleContinentSelection(with indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let continent = continentData[indexPath.row]

    for country in countryData {
        if (country.continent?.continentName)! == continent {
            itemSelection.append(country.countryName!)

            if let index = countryData.lastIndex(of: country) {
                collectionView?.selectItem(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: 2), animated: false, scrollPosition: [])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As illustrated above, all collectionview selections have a different way of handling the selection. If I select something in section 1, I also select cells in section 2.

The selected and deselected state are being handled in the subclass like this;

```
class FRMenuCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            if super.isSelected == true {
                self.label.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.label.text!, attributes: FRSharedStyles.filledTextAttributes)
            } else {
                self.label.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.label.text!, attributes: FRSharedStyles.opaqueStrokeTextAttributes)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the selected state is filled text, the deselected state is outlined. Everything works fine, it just renders slowly on my apple TV when scrolling fast (with the side scroll it's most noticable). Any ideas on how to optimise this would be appreciated.